# Reanimated 2 compatibility with SDK 44

Tags: expo, react-native-reanimated-v2

```
SDK Version: Expo 44.0.6
Platforms(Android/iOS/web/all): Android / iOS
Tested versions of react-native-reanimated : 2.2.4, 2.3.1, 2.4.1, 2.5.0
```

I recently upgraded my expo bare native workflow app from SDK41 to 44 (following all blog guidelines) using expo upgrade.

I’m stuck with this error : App freezes on simulator or real device when remote debugger is active (Expo Modules, Apple Silicon M1) · Issue #14875 · expo/expo · GitHub

The crash on Android (with v2.3.1 compatible version given by expo) is :

> A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x454c4b524f5777 in tid 30501 (create_react_co), pid 30355 (m.em.butterlink)

I’m using react native navigation v5, which requires reanimated to work.

If I understand well, “you can’t use remote debugging with 'turbomodules'”.

So first question, can I just have my code running in debug mode (updated without needing to rebuild with android studio) without remote debug ?
I tried to enable 'hermes' following Expo guidelines (in app.json) in my android project and to setup Flipper but crash is still there, how can I setup those two in a bare workflow project to solve this issue and be able to code in debug mode again ?

https://forums.expo.dev/t/reanimated-2-compatibility-with-sdk-44/62831

Comment: Same issue. I don't see this mentioned nearly anywhere on the web and I have no idea why it's not mentioned in the Expo Upgrade Guide for SDK 44.

Comment: So frustrating, have you found anything that can help?